# Schur-Weyl Duality for algebraic groups over a finite field

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I will reference https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610591.pdf as [Dot1] and 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1235.pdf as [Dot2].

The setting is the following: Let $k$ be a finite field, $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ elements and we view $V_1: SL_2\subset GL_2$ as a representation of the algebraic group $SL_2$ over $k$.

In a proof I read right now, the author uses the statement, that the map given by permutation of elementary tensors
$$k[S_n]\rightarrow End_{SL_2}(V_1^{\otimes n})$$
is surjective and that the $k$-dimension on the right hand side is independent on the field $k$. As a reasoning for this, the author references [Dot1, Proposition 14 and 15], but there, they work with an infinite field $K$, the algebraic group $GL_2$ instead of $SL_2$, and the $K$-valued points $GL_2(K)$ of $GL_2$. If I change the reference to [Dot2, Corollary 4.4] they also work with $SL_2$ and not only with $GL_2$, but the rest of the differences in the statement above vs. the statements in the references still confuse me.